# How do you lock a member variable in perl?

Tags: perl

I wrote a script in perl which does multi-threading, I then tried to convert it over into an object.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to lock on a member variable.  The closest I've come to is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
package Y;
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;

sub new
{
  my $class = shift;
  my $val :shared = 0;
  my $self =
  {
    x => \$val
  };
  bless $self, $class;
  is_shared($self->{x}) or die "nope";
  return $self;
}

package MAIN;
use warnings;
use strict;
use threads;
use threads::shared;
use Data::Dumper;

my $x = new Y();
{
  lock($x->{x});
}
print Dumper('0');                 # prints: $VAR = '0';
print Dumper($x->{x});             # prints: $VAR = \'0';
print "yes\n" if ($x->{x} == 0);   # prints nothing
#print "yes\n" if ($$x->{x} == 0);  # dies with msg: Not a SCALAR reference
my $tmp = $x->{x};                 # this works.  Must be a order of precedence thing.
print "yes\n" if ($$tmp == 0);     # prints: yes


#++$$x->{x};                        # dies with msg: Not a SCALAR reference
++$$tmp;
print Dumper($x->{x});             # prints: $VAR = \'1';
```

This allows me to put a lock on the member var `x`, but it means I'd be needing 2 member variables as the actual member var isn't really capable of being manipulated by assigning to it, incrementing it, etc.  I can't even test against it.

**EDIT**:

I'm thinking that I should rename this question *"How do you dereference a member variable in perl?"* as the problem seems to boil down to that.  Using `$$x->{x}` is invalid syntax and you can't force precedence rules with parentheses.  I.e. `$($x->{x})` doesn't work.  Using a temporary works but it a nuisance.

Comment: There are no threads in your sample code.

Comment: @mob I didn't add actual threads as it's not necessary to show that it doesn't work.  If I try and lock on a member var, it'll die/croak.  The `is_shared()` function also shows that it's not shareable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't get what you are trying to do with threads and locking, but there are some simple errors in the way you use references.

```
$x->{x}
```

is a reference to a scalar, so the expressions

```
$x->{x} == 0
++$$x->{x}
```

both look suspect. `$$x->{x}` is parsed as `{$$x}->{x}` (dereference `$x`, then treat it as a hash reference and look up the value with key `x`). I think you mean to say

```
${$x->{x}} == 0
++${$x->{x}}
```

where `${$x->{x}}` means to treat `$x` as a hash reference, to look up the value for key `x` in that hash, and then to dererence that value.

Comment: That's what it is, I tried using parentheses before and not braces.  Thanks.